# Replace with Regular Expression in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a text like `(:year)` i want to extract the year and replace it with 1.
I am using

```
replaceAll("\\:[a-z A-Z]+?($|\\W)", "1");
```

This gives me the answer(1. It removes the closing bracket. What change should i make to exclude this closing bracket.

Input may be like (:year), :year , :year xxxx, and :year may be at the end of string. Using this in JAVA

Comment: Why are you matching on any word after `:` when you only want to match on `year`?

Comment: its just an example it may not be year it may be :month or :time or :variable anything..

Comment: But don't you need to know the word in order to know what the replacement value should be?

Comment: @Andreas I am  not using any word in that expression

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
replaceAll("\\:[a-zA-Z]+\\b", "1");
```

Simply use `\b` or `word boundary`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/71

Comment: The expression can be improved by removing the space between `z` and `A`, and the `?` after the `+`.

Comment: @AnoopLL `\b` was made for this purpose ..to detect word boundaries.

Comment: @AnoopLL may i know why you added space inside the character class?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but colon `:` doesn't need to be escaped, does it?

Comment: @Andreas no not really

Answer (score 1):

Turn the second group as positive lookahead. Positive lookahead are assertions which won't capture any characters but asserts whether a match is possible or not.

```
string.replaceAll("\\:[a-z A-Z]+?(?=$|\\W)", "1");
```